# Multiple arrays searching and return the arrays where a value fits

Tags: php, arrays, search

I'm a little newbie on php and I struggle to solve this problem.
I have the following structure:

X1...X2...X3 .....X20

1...2....8

2...3...11

4...6....18

6...9....13

8...10...16

10...11...18

... etc.

30 rows for each.

Now I have a variable, let's say $var=7.
How do I return the value of the colums where it finds. In this case the result should be X1,X2.

If $var=16 result should be X3
If $var =10 result should be X1,X2,X3.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't understand the structure of your data and what you are trying to find. Could you clearify?

Comment: I re-edited the post at it was a mess :).

Comment: My approch is to define arrays for each x...something like $x1 = array (1,2,4,6,8,10), $x2 etc..... Then find the value $var in which array's range exists. As in my example $var=7 is in array's X1 range and X2.

Answer (score 0):

I would put all your ranges inside an array, iterate over them and use in_array to find wich ranges contains what you search for.

```
$ranges = [
    'x1' => [1,2,8],
    'x2' => [2,3,11],
    'x2' => [4,6,18]
];
$res = [];
$search = 4;
foreach(ranges as $rangeName => $range){
    if(in_array($range,$search)){
        $res[] = $rangeName;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank's, it works after some improvement.

```
<?php 
$ranges = [
    'x1' => [1,2,8],
    'x2' => [2,3,11],
    'x3' => [5,6,18],
];
$res = [];
$search = 4;
foreach($ranges as $rangeName => $range){
 $min = min($range);
 $max = max($range);
$interval=range($min,$max);
    if(in_array($search,$interval)){
        $res[] = $rangeName;
echo $rangeName."<br/>";
    }
}
?> }
```

This is SOLVED, but only for integers!

Now, the hard part :)... if the ranges are floting numbers with 2 decimal as
'x4' => [0.27,1.93,8.92], the code dosen't find it as a "good range", even if $search =4 is in the range.
In my real app the ranges and $search number are floating 2 decimals...
So, any ideas ?